# display of blocks in responsive version

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have 6 images wrapped inside an outer `div`.

I'd like to see 2 images per row in the mobile version, so there should be 3 columns with 2 images per row.

I have this HTML:

```css
           * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.picture-box {
  width: 70%; /* limit screen width - max width could have been used aswell */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ring {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center; /* Center ring div */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   .ring {
      width: 25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
   .ring {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .ring {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .picture-box {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

.thumb {
    display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-box">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7hf41esz/)

I tried to change `flex-direction` from `row` to `column`, but it did not help. 
I may need to write widths for them, but do not know how and now I cannot make them into a column.
How can I solve that?

Comment: @Marc Hjorth, it doesnt work as I want. In responsive version there are no 2 blocks in a row. Can you help me in this question, please?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

I used `width` like you asked about in your question - this is one way to do it.

This way you can control how many boxes (`.ring's`) you want to show in each breakpoint.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.picture-box {
  width: 70%; /* limit screen width - max width could have been used aswell */
  margin: 0 auto; /* center content */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.ring {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center; /* Center ring div */
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
   .ring {
      width: 25%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
   .ring {
      width: 33.33%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .ring {
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .picture-box {
      width: 100%;
    }
}

.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="picture-box">
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ring">
    <div class="thumb">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rsgozuyw/)

Comment: I changed my code in question. Please look at it. I need to see blocks in computer version in a column, but in mobile version 2 block in a row.

Comment: What do you mean you need to see blocks in computer version on a column? Can you explain further? @asdas

Comment: yes. I need to see them on a column in computer version, but in mobile 2 block in a row. Thus, in mobile version there will be 3 rows with 2 block in each row.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by columns on desktop. The mobile version is already showing 3 rows with 2 blocks in each row

Comment: yes. in computer version all works as I want, but in mobile version 2 block in each row does not work

Comment: What browser do you use? It seems to work fine. Look at [this screenshot](http://prntscr.com/moirr4)

Comment: can you send me the link? and is in this example blocks in column in comuter version?

Comment: Check the answer @asdas

Comment: @Mach Hjorth, I checked it, and in computer version blocks are not in columnn:(